# Upload Multiple files to remote FTP Server using php

Tags: php, file, upload, ftp

I need to use php to upload to an ftp server 4 files. I have the following example code, that I am working from. How could this code be changed to upload multiple files that were already on the server (not uploaded at the time of the ftp transfer).

Lets say I have 4 files in a subfolder relative to the php file that does the upload, lets call the subfolder “/fileshere/” with the following 4 files in it:

file1.zip
file2.zip
file3.zip
file4.zip

I need the script to upload each of the files, then give a done message.

Below is the starting code I am using and trying to adapt. Any help would be much appreciated:

```
$ftp_server = "ftp.yourserver.com";
$ftp_user_name = "ftpuser";
$ftp_user_pass = "ftppassword";
$remote_dir = "/target/folder/on/ftp/server";

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = @ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

//default values
$file_url = "";

if($login_result) {
//set passive mode enabled
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

//check if directory exists and if not then create it
if(!@ftp_chdir($conn_id, $remote_dir)) {
//create diectory
ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $remote_dir);
//change directory
ftp_chdir($conn_id, $remote_dir);
}

$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$remote_file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

$ret = ftp_nb_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY, FTP_AUTORESUME);
while(FTP_MOREDATA == $ret) {
$ret = ftp_nb_continue($conn_id);
}

if($ret == FTP_FINISHED) {
echo "File '" . $remote_file . "' uploaded successfully.";
} else {
echo "Failed uploading file '" . $remote_file . "'.";
}
} else {
echo "Cannot connect to FTP server at " . $ftp_server;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the code?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The code above is for single file transfers after an upload. I need the code to use files that are at preset locations on a server! And more then just 1

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
<?php
// connect and login data
$web = 'www.website.com';
$user = 'admin';
$pass = 'password';
// file location
$server_file = '/public_html/example.txt';
$local_file = 'example.txt';
//connect
$conn_id = ftp_connect($web);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id,$user,$pass);
//uploading
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $server_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY))
 {echo "Success";} 
else {echo "Failed";}
?>
```

if you want to upload multiple files just put your files names into array then put whole code into for loop .